# How can we define temperature in integrable systems?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, many-body, integrable-systems

For a thermalised system, at equilibrium, the usual quantum statistical ensembles are valid and we can define temperature at an equilibrium between system and its bath. But for integrable systems (non-thermalisable) we don't have those ensembles, so how do we define a temperature?

PS- I had this doubt specific to many body localized state. And my intution is that the ensemble for a many body localised state would be similar to any other integrable system. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, to describe thermalization in integrable models one should to pass to the so-called "generalized Gibbs ensemble". For a prototypical integrable model, the XXX spin chain, the former was constructed by Ilievski *et al* [arXiv:1507.02993](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.02993); see also [arXiv:1610.06911](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.06911). (For the dynamics, away from thermal equilibrium, the key concept is "generalized hydrodynamics", see e.g. [J. Dubail's Viewpoint in Physics](https://physics.aps.org/articles/v9/153))

Comment: Wrt many-body localisation you could take a look at Moore's slides at https://indico.in2p3.fr/event/14018/page/2 (see also those of Doyon).